# Need help creating a simple program to convert Mb to Kb in Visual Basic [Noob]

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

Noob here who has taken a computing class and has just started learning Visual Basic using Visual Studio. My first task is to research online and create a simple console application that converts Megabytes to Kilobytes.

```
Module 
    Sub Main() 
      Dim Kb As Integer 
      Console.WriteLine("Enter Number of Megabytes") 
      Kb = Console.ReadLine / 1024 
      Console.WriteLine(Kb) 
  End Sub 
End Module
```

This is far as I have come after looking around the internet, (yes, very noobish!) not exactly sure where I go from here or know if I am even doing it right.

It would be much appreciated if someone could help me out with some code. Thanks!

Comment: You can't multiply by 1024?

Answer (score 2):

Well, `1MB` is equals to `1024KB`.  So, multiply the input (in MB) by `1024`.

```
Dim kb As Integer = 0
Console.WriteLine("Enter Number of Megabytes")
kb = Integer.Parse(Console.ReadLine()) * 1024
Console.WriteLine(kb.ToString())
Console.ReadLine()
```

Comment: I do know how to convert mb to kb, but I don't know how I am supposed to write the code which allows the user to input any value in mb, within the console and get a response with the result in kb. If you do know could you please post the code, that would be great! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In the good ol' days 1024 was the number to use.  Today it is not so easy.  For memory 1024 is still appropriate but for other things, e.g. disk size, it may not be.  See:

http://physics.nist.gov/cuu/Units/prefixes.html
   and
http://physics.nist.gov/cuu/Units/binary.html

Comment: I agree, but it sounds like this was just a small application for learning VB.NET.